# With Logbook and ZeroMQ, why do I need to wait to be able to pass messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeromq, pyzmq, logbook

**Code description:**
My code is simple, it starts a **`ZeroMQHandler`** (socket based messaging) from the Logbook library (using pyzmq). The Logger (log) runs throughout the application. Finally, the handler closes the port. The **`.push()`** and **`.pop_application()`** methods are there instead of the
`with handler.applicationbound():` and indent.

**Purpose:**
I'm testing this queue based messaging to see if it can be a low-impact asynchronous logging solution. I need to log about 15 000 messages per second. I'd prefer to use Python, but my fallback is writing the logger in C++ and exposing its handles to python.

**The issue:**
The issue is that if I don't wait a *quarter of a second* or more after opening the handler(socket), the program executes without any messages getting through (the test program takes less than 0.25 seconds to execute). This I interpret as being a set-up time needed for the ZeroMQ socket or something like that. So I'm reaching out to see if anyone has a similar experience, maybe this is documented anywhere, but I can't seem to figure it out by myself. I want to know why this is needed. Thanks for any input.

my working code looks something like this :

```
from logbook.queues import ZeroMQHandler
from logbook import Logger
import time

addr='tcp://127.0.0.1:5053'
handler = ZeroMQHandler(addr)
time.sleep(0.25) ################################################# THIS ! ####

log = Logger("myLogbook")
handler.push_application()

log.info("start of program")
foo()
log.info("end of program")

handler.close()
handler.pop_application()
```

receiver, running in different python kernel (for tests, gives output to stdout):

```
from logbook.queues import ZeroMQSubscriber
from logbook import Logger, StreamHandler
import sys
import time
addr='tcp://127.0.0.1:5053'
print("ZeroMQSubscriber begin with address {}".format(addr))
subscriber = ZeroMQSubscriber(addr)
handler = StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

log = Logger("A receiver")
handler.push_application()


try:
    i=0
    while True:
        i += 1
        record = subscriber.recv(2)
        if not record:
            pass # timeout
        else:
            print("got message!")
            log.handle(record)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("C-C caught, program end after {} iterations".format(i))    
handler.pop_application()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZeroMQ indeed spends some time to create a **`Context()`**-instance per-se, it then asks O/S to allocate memory-bound resources, to spawn I/O-threads, which also takes some additional time. Next, each **`Socket()`**-instantiation consumes some add-on overhead time.

It is well documented in both the native API-documentation and in educational resources, that asynchronous signalling / messaging framework does spend some time, before any API-request actually gets processed inside the both "local" and "remote" `Context()`-instances and finally marked as a deliverable readable for the "remote"-end of some of the ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Archetype.

This said, there ought be no surprise, that an even more re-wrapped use of ZeroMQ tools ( re-wrapped by another level of abstraction, coded into the  **`logbook.queue.ZeroMQSubscriber, logbook.queue.ZeroMQHandler`** classes ), will only add additional `{` setup & operational `}`-overheads, so the known asynchronicity of the service will only grow.

If your application requires any sort of mutual reconfirmation between any pair of the both ends that they have reached a **R**eady-**T**o-**O**perate state ( **RTO**-state ), the best would be to introduce some sort of smart-reconciliation policy, instead of remaining in a blind belief, relying on a long enough `.sleep()` to hope the things were let enough time to settle down and got into RTO.

In [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) there is always better be explicit, rather than remaining in an optimistic hope.

---

### Epilogue:

Given your sustained throughput ought safely go under and also remain under the **expected threshold of `<= 66 [us/message]`** per message dispatched, let me also raise an interest into a proper **`Context()`**-parametrisation, so as to be indeed smoothly carrying your required workload under realistic hardware and system-wide resources planning.

Default values are not hammered into a stone and never ought be a point to rely on.